# how to combine multiple observables on first observable complete and return as new observable in method

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

I am a beginner to use RxJs operators and I am having a requirement of a method, which calls 5 observables from service and it should fetch data from service only after first observable completes,  then combine all the observables and transform to a new observable and return a new observable with in a function. The below code illustrates the scenario.

```
GetAllDetails(): Observable<AllDetails> {

const user = this.service.getUser() // Observable<User>
const firstDetails = this.service.getFirstDetail() // returns Observable<FirstDetail>
const secondDetails = this.service.getSecondDetail() // returns Observable<SecondDetail>
const thirdDetails = this.service.getThirdDetail() // returns Observable<ThirdDetail>
const fourthDetails = this.service.getFourthDetail() // returns Observable<FourthDetail>

// need to return a value that something compatible with Observable<AllDetails>
// so the logic should check if user info available then do combining all observable values and 
// return as new observable 

return of(new AllDetails(first, second, third, fourth) 
}
```

I tried using CombineLatest and switchMap, but I cannot achieve this after my first observable complete. Appreciate if someone could help me out on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```js
return user.pipe(
  last(), // Get the lastest value when the `user$` completes
  switchMap(
    user => conditionOnUser 
      ? forkJoin({ first: firstDetails, second: secondDetails /* ... */ })
      : of(null)
  ),
  map(
    detailsOrNull => !detailsOrNull
      ? false // No user info available
      : new AllDetails(detailsOrNull.first, detailsOrNull.second /* ... */)
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. Is it possible to include user info in AllDetails too?

Comment: Sure, you could just add another property to the object passed to `forkJoin`: `forkJoin({ 
first: firstDetails, ..., user: of(user) })`. Then, the object is available in the outer `map`

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I tried this and this works for me. Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).

`forkJoin` is the easiest way, when you need to wait for multiple HTTP requests to be resolved.

Example:

```
public fetchDataFromMultipleSources(): Observable<any[]> {
let response1 = this.http.get(url1).subscribe((response) => {
  let response2 = this.http.get(url2);
  let response3 = this.http.get(url3);
  return forkJoin([response1, response2, response3]);
});
return response1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manish. But, I want to return multiple observables after first observable completes in a method. can you tell me how to check that?

Comment: Do you mean `getFirstDetail`, `getSecondDetail` etc should be called when `this.service.getUser()` complete?

Comment: Thanks for the update Manish. I agree this also works! However, I tried @Andrei's solution and hence accepted. Kindly don't mistake me.

Comment: Sure. Good to know that our answers helped you. All the best!